# Save optimised CSS from Firebug?

Tags: css, firebug

When inspecting an element in Firebug you are shown a list of CSS with overridden properties crossed out. Are you able to extract all of the non overridden CSS active on one page into a file? Alternatively is there another tool able to parse stylesheets deleting properties which have been usurped by those later in the file?

My use case (although not specifically relevant to the principle I'm trying to achieve) is editing an existing Wordpress theme with the CSS is spread out over several files with lots of overlapping styles. I'm happy with the current appearance in the browser and just want to grab all the active CSS, drop it into one file and ditch the rest.

Comment: if you dump all the styles this way, and create a stylesheet for an element from it, your CSS will actually be *de*optimised rather than optimised. It might give you the results you want, but that certainly isn't the recommended way to write CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want, but it may still do what you need. Take a look at cssUpdater

Its a firefox add-on and accompanying air application that can update the actual CSS file as you make changes in Firebug. Quite useful and time saving.

Another way is to use the CSS edit capability of the Web Developer add-on for Firefox.

[Firediff](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions#Firediff) is another firebug add-on that can show you changes to your CSS from its original state as you tweak things in Firebug.

Comment: I was going to recommend http://code.google.com/p/css-x-fire/ but it seems that CSSUpdater is based off it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just dump all the CSS into one file. Make sure that all the files appear in the order that they would be called on the website, so that the styles are optimized correctly and the correct overrides are used. Positioning within the document is important.

Then you can just run that file through any automated CSS optimizer on the web, such as this one:
http://www.cssoptimiser.com/

I use an optimizer whenever I write a new CSS file, just to make sure that my CSS is as accurate as it can be.